# Create a user list of current access users

Tags: vba

I'm trying to create a table in Access that holds the current users computer name that are in the system.

The code I have so far is

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub ShowUserRosterMultipleUsers()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i, j As Long

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

Dim dbs As Database, tbl As TableDef, fld As Field
Set dbs = CurrentDb

Set tbl = dbs.CreateTableDef("Users")
Set fld = tbl.CreateField("User#", dbText)

' The user roster is exposed as a provider-specific schema rowset
' in the Jet 4.0 OLE DB provider.  You have to use a GUID to
' reference the schema, as provider-specific schemas are not
' listed in ADO's type library for schema rowsets

Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, _
, "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")

'Output the list of all users in the current database.

Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Name, "", rs.Fields(1).Name, _
"", rs.Fields(2).Name, rs.Fields(3).Name

While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0), rs.Fields(1), _
    rs.Fields(2), rs.Fields(3)
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

tbl.Fields.Append ?

End Sub
```

The code I found and updated a bit works, but it only outputs to the immediate window, which the debug.print should, but I need to create a table with all the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's stopping you? Create a table, and replace the call to `Debug.Print` with code that appends a row to the table and sets the field values. You already have code that shows you how to read the fields from a dataset (`rs.Fields()`).

Comment: I've added the create table function, at this point I'm not sure how to call this into another table.  I guess I'm having trouble with setting rs.fields(0), which is all I need, so I can call it into the table.  Your answer has yielded some different ideas for searches on google, I'll keep trying, thanks.

Comment: Inside your `While Not rs.Eof` loop, `tbl.Append` to add a new record. `tbl.Fields(0)` gives you access to the first field, just like `rs.Fields(0)` gives you access to the first field of the recordset. `.Value` reads and/or writes from the field, IIRC.

Comment: Okay I get where your coming from, I'm still not 100% sure what to do.  I'm unable to find tbl.append, I did find <TBL>.APPEND(), but I've never used that and not sure it will work with vba in an access 2010 database.  What I can find is tbl.fields.append ().  Though I'm still not sure how to call in the rs.fields, I want to say I need to set/dim it as something to call it to append it.

Comment: No,  you don't want to *append a new field*. You want to *append a new record*. I don't have Access on this machine; it could be `tbl.Insert` instead. You could also Google "Access VBA append record" and see what you find;, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243801%28v=office.12%29.aspx) seems like it would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, I've found a few, but each one requires you to name the item to insert.  Where I fall short, I don't know how to tell it to use the rs.fields(0).  I'll keep looking, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, funny thing this has been asked before on this site, will have to try searching better next time.

my code which works is as follows

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Sub ShowUserRosterMultipleUsers()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i, j As Long
Dim db As Database
Dim rsDao As DAO.Recordset

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsDao = db.OpenRecordset("Users", dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly + dbFailOnError)

' The user roster is exposed as a provider-specific schema rowset
' in the Jet 4.0 OLE DB provider.  You have to use a GUID to
' reference the schema, as provider-specific schemas are not
' listed in ADO's type library for schema rowsets

Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, _
, "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")

'Output the list of all users in the current database.
Do While Not rs.EOF
    rsDao.AddNew
    rsDao!User.Value = rs.Fields(0)
    rsDao.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

This assumes you have a database with a table named "Users" with a column in it called "User", very original I know.

Tested it and it brings in the one user me, and it should bring in any others that are in the database as well.

Thanks for all your help Ken.

Comment: When i use this code, i do get 4 lines in rs.Fields, when 4 users are online, but i get the computer ID 4 times, from the first computer that opened the file this morning. Do you know what to do about this?